# Calculate number of rows in a dataframe, before a specified value based on only future rows after each row, in r

Tags: r, sequence

I have a dataframe such as the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"),
  V2 = c(1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2011),
  V3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
)
```

I am trying to create a new column, V4, which has values for the number of consecutive years (`V2`) within group `V1` before V3 goes from 0 to 1. I use the following code:

```
data %>%
  arrange(V1, V2) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(
    V4 = ifelse(V3 == 1, 0, seq_along(V2) - which.max(lead(V3, default = 0) == 1) - 1)
  )
```

But this gives me the output:

```
a   1995    0   -8  
a   1996    0   -7  
a   1997    0   -6  
a   1998    0   -5  
a   1999    0   -4  
a   2000    0   -3  
a   2001    0   -2  
a   2002    0   -1  
a   2003    1   0   
a   2004    0   1   
a   2005    1   0   
a   2006    0   3   
a   2007    0   4   
a   2008    0   5   
a   2009    0   6   
a   2010    0   7   
a   2011    1   0
```

The problem with this is that it handles the first case of switched `V3` to 1 properly, and calculates the number of years before the switch properly (with negatives, as they should be). However, it messes up on every case where there are multiple switches. I want the count of years to reset on every switch of `V2`, so that it only calculates the future years before there is another switch in `V2`. So the desired output would be the following:

```
a   1995    0   -8  
a   1996    0   -7  
a   1997    0   -6  
a   1998    0   -5  
a   1999    0   -4  
a   2000    0   -3  
a   2001    0   -2  
a   2002    0   -1  
a   2003    1   0   
a   2004    0   -1  
a   2005    1   0   
a   2006    0   -5  
a   2007    0   -4  
a   2008    0   -3  
a   2009    0   -2  
a   2010    0   -1  
a   2011    1   0
```

And if there are no future years where `V3` = 1, then `V4` should just default to -1. How can I code this in r, so that the number of years before `V3` is 1 is only future years, for each specific row where `V3` is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by `dplyr::consecutive_id(V3)` to compute years until switch, then use `rev(cumsum(rev(V3)))` to identify where there are no `1`s left.

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(tmp = consecutive_id(V3), .by = V1) %>%
  mutate(
    V4 = ifelse(V3 == 1, 0, -rev(seq_along(V2))),
    .by = c(V1, tmp)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    V4 = ifelse(rev(cumsum(rev(V3))) == 0, -1, V4),
    tmp = NULL,
    .by = V1
  )
```

Result:

```r
   V1   V2 V3 V4
1   a 1995  0 -8
2   a 1996  0 -7
3   a 1997  0 -6
4   a 1998  0 -5
5   a 1999  0 -4
6   a 2000  0 -3
7   a 2001  0 -2
8   a 2002  0 -1
9   a 2003  1  0
10  a 2004  0 -1
11  a 2005  1  0
12  a 2006  0 -5
13  a 2007  0 -4
14  a 2008  0 -3
15  a 2009  0 -2
16  a 2010  0 -1
17  a 2011  1  0
18  a 2011  1  0
```

Comment: after your first `group_by` why not mutate by `V4 = (row_number() - n() - 1 )*!V3`??

Comment: That would work too!